# Magento access denied error while creating an order from admin

Tags: magento

Users of a particular role are unable to create orders in Magento admin, they get "Access denied" error.

Cache is disabled and this even exists for a new user, so cookies are not a problem here.

I couldn't trace this down to any recent change in codebase and I am clueless how it creep in. Any pointers on how should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: have u tried after logout after login.

Comment: @gowri I even created a new account and the problem persists, so its not a cookie related issue. Any thing else that it might be?

Comment: Have you checked all checkbox the under Role Resource sales to the role.

Comment: @gowri yep! only have the edit action unchecked. rest all are checked. I even tried with edit action being checked but that didnt change anything

Comment: Two NAA's are pointing to *SUPEE-6285 (security patch)* as possible reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating a new role with the exact same permissions and then moved all the users to it.